# change background color of select box options

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

I have a drop-down menu in a form on a website that I'd like to change the background of the options to be transparent like the initial selection.

I use `background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)` for that, but how do I apply it to the `<option>`'s.

NOTE: [This is a Wordpress site](http://winghammotel.com.au/bookings) and the form is generated by a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t do that in a cross-browser way, all browser have different default "non-overridable" styles they apply to selects.

There are javascript/jquery plugins you can use if you are willing to apply a javascript layer on top of you select box that replaces it with more styleable elements.

Comment: I'm willing to try that... I'm already calling the latest jqueryui library.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change css of the option :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("option").css("background", "none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2");
});
```